# Rebus: Don't make me angry

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus

**Guess what this rebus represents???**

[image]

> **HINT:** It's a phrase. Not a single word.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is

> Go to Hell

Because

> As DrunkWolf pointed out, the first part with the numbers points to GoTo0, a user on this site.  The second part works like this... start with "handbell".  Remove the "b" (the bee image is cutout of the image), and remove the "and" (the AND gate image is also cutout), leaving "hell"

Comment: Yes! Much love for finding it, would've driven me crazy haha, in hindsight it's so silly that i didn't see it,..

Comment: I hope this message was directed to no one...

Comment: Doesn't make as much sense when you think the bottom image on the bell is a power cord.

Comment: @Kevin.  Nope.  Being a programmer _sometimes_ has it's benefits

Comment: @APrough Is it bad that I am a programmer?

Comment: @Kevin.  Nope, it's a good thing.  How about me rephrasing as "a programmer that is usually _forced_ to draw logic gates to explain to non-programmers"?

Answer (score 11):

First part is definetely

> Goto, or go-to. Puzzling user 4394 is GOTO-0, -0 = GOTO

Second part i'm struggling a bit, but it might be

> Bibel Connection? Bee - Bell - Connection?

Comment: the second silhoutte looks like a "and gate"

Comment: @kanchirk i actually considered that as well, but i have an even harder time placing that inside (and probably at the end of) a sentence..

Comment: 'go to bible-land'? :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf I think we should figure out the connection to the title.

Comment: @kanchirk indeed, my new thoughts on the gate could actually be that it stands for 'and', taking a bit of liberty with pronounciation it could then be included in the bell, to spell bellend.. but got to be bellend.. go to be bellend, none of those work as a sentence for me, so definetely still missing something